# ViewPager does not redraw content on swipe back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**Problem**

I am new to android and i am using viewpager for the first time in my app and
i am suffering from very strange behavior in my app that is i am using viewpager with three fragments ( TrackFragment , AlbumFragment , ArtistFragment ) and when i swip page from **TrackFragment** to **AlbumFragment** and again come back to **TrackFragment** it becomes blank (but it was not at first time when i am at **TrackFragment** initially) and same thing happened when i jump to **ArtistFragment** or any other fragments from the tab layout (its become blank).

And in case when i am going to **ArtistFragment** from **TrackFragment** via **AlbumFragments** by swiping the pages it works correctly (that is contents are shown in pages).

Please suggest me a method to overcome the above problem or any other method to implement same thing.
Here is my code....

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String[] mPlanetTitles={"Tracks","Album","Artist"};
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
Fragment [] fragments = {new TracksFragment(),new AlbumFragment(), new ArtistFragment()};
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
   ViewPager viewPager;
   public static ImageView im;
   int pos= -1 ;
   public static Context context;
   MusicService musicService;
   boolean mBound;
   TabLayout tabLayout ;
   public static Uri currentsonguri;
   protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("lastplayed",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

       Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MusicService.class);
       startService(i);
       mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
       mDrawerList.setAdapter(new NavigationDrawerAdapter(this));
       mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               if(position == 3)
               {
                   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlaylistActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
               }
               if(position == 4)
               {
                   Intent intent = new Intent();
                   intent.setAction("android.media.action.DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL");
                   if((intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)) {
                       startActivity(intent);
                   } else {
                       // No equalizer found :(
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No Equaliser Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               }

           }
       });

       tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
       viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
       tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.DKGRAY,Color.WHITE);
       tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
       context = getBaseContext();
       pagerAdapter = new myfragment(getSupportFragmentManager());


       im  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.currentsong);
               viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
               viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
               tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager,true);

       SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPreferences.edit();
       if(sharedPreferences.getInt("count",0)==0)
       {
           editor.putInt("count",1);
       }
       else
       {
           int c= sharedPreferences.getInt("count",0);
           Log.d("Uses count",c+"");
           editor.putInt("count",c++);
           editor.apply();
       }
       if(!sharedPreferences.getString("uri","").equals(""))
       {
          String s = sharedPreferences.getString("uri","");
           Uri u = Uri.parse(s);
           currentsonguri = u;
           MediaMetadataRetriever data=new MediaMetadataRetriever();
           data.setDataSource(getBaseContext(),u);
           try {
               byte[] b = data.getEmbeddedPicture();
               Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
               bitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap);
               im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           try {
               musicService.setsongbyuri(u,getBaseContext());
               musicService.setMediaPlayer();
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
       else
       {

       }
       editor.apply();
       im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MusicPlayerActivity.class);
          intent.setData(currentsonguri);
          intent.putExtra("flag",1);
          startActivity(intent);
      }
  });



       final Uri r= getIntent().getData();
          if(r!=null) {
              currentsonguri = r;
              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MusicPlayerActivity.class);
              intent.setData(r);
              intent.putExtra("flag",0);
              startActivity(intent);

          }
       }

public class myfragment extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    myfragment(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String s = "non";
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0 : s= "Tracks" ;
                break;
            case 1: s= "Albums" ;
                break;
            case 2: s= "Artist" ;
                break;
        }
        return s;
    }


}

public void setview(byte [] b, int position,Uri uri)
{
    currentsonguri = uri;
    Log.d("position in set view",""+position);
    Log.d("fail","i am here");
    if(im!=null)
    {
        if(b!=null)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
            bitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap);
            im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else {
            songDetailloader loader = new songDetailloader(context);
            String s = loader.albumartwithalbum(loader.songalbum(position));
            Log.d("fail","fail to set small image");
            if (s != null) {
                im.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s));
                Log.d("fail","nowsetting set small image");
            } else {
                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_track_light);
                Log.d("ic","ic_launcher setted");
            }

        }
    }
    else {
        Log.d(""," im is null");
    }
}



public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = 100;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}


private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MusicService.LocalBinder binder = (MusicService.LocalBinder) service;
        musicService  =  binder.getService();
        mBound =true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mBound =false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("MainActivity","Get distoryed");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MusicService.class);
    bindService(i, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unbindService(serviceConnection);

}}
```

**Tracks Fragment**

```
public class TracksFragment extends Fragment {
songDetailloader loader = new songDetailloader();
ArrayList<Songs> give = new ArrayList<>();
public int pos = -1;
MediaPlayer mp ;
MusicService musicService;
boolean mBound;
ImageView search;
ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
RelativeLayout editreltive;
ListView listView;
EditText editText;
TextView ch;
private Cursor cursor ;
int albumindex,dataindex,titleindex,durationindex,artistindex;
private final static String[] columns ={MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC,MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE ,MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID};
private final String where = "is_music AND duration > 10000 AND _size <> '0' ";
private final String orderBy =  MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
public TracksFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("fragment created","created");
    setRetainInstance(true);


}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewofsongs,container,false);
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    allsongs();
    intlistview();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),MusicService.class);
            getActivity().bindService(i, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    }).start();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Log.d("Uri of ",""+give.get(position).getSonguri());
            musicService.setplaylist(give,give.get(position).getPosition());
            musicService.setMediaPlayer();
            view.setSelected(true);
        }
    });
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            View v =LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.select_dialog_layout,null);
            builder.setView(v);
            builder.setTitle(give.get(position).gettitle()+"\n  "+give.get(position).getalbum());
            builder.create();
            final AlertDialog d=builder.show();

            //seting click listner.....
            TextView play = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogplay);
            TextView playnext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogplaynext);
            TextView queue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogqueue);
            TextView fav = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogaddtofav);
            TextView album = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogalbum);
            TextView artist = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogartist);
            TextView playlist = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogaddtoplaylsit);
            TextView share = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogshare);
            TextView delete = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogdelete);
            TextView properties = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogproperties);
            play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    File f= new File(give.get(position).getSonguri().getLastPathSegment());
                    Log.d("LENGTH IS",""+f.length());
                    musicService.setplaylist(give,position);
                    musicService.setMediaPlayer();
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });
            playnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    d.dismiss();

                }
            });
            queue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    d.dismiss();
                    musicService.insertinqueue(give.get(position));
                }
            });

            fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    d.dismiss();
                    DataBaseClass db = new DataBaseClass(getContext());
                    int i=db.insetintoliked(give.get(position));
                    if(i==1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Added to Favorites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Already in Favorites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            album.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    d.dismiss();
                    Intent i = new Intent( getActivity() , AlbumDetail.class);
                    Bundle b= new Bundle();
                    b.putCharSequence("album",give.get(position).getalbum());
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            artist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),ArtistActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("artist",give.get(position).getartist());
                    startActivity(i);
                    d.dismiss();

                }
            });
            playlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    d.dismiss();

                }
            });
            delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                        b.setMessage("Audio '"+give.get(position).gettitle()+"' will be deleted permanently !");
                        b.setTitle("Delete ?");
                        b.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                d.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        b.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            File f= new File(give.get(position).getSonguri().getPath());
                            boolean b = f.delete();
                            Log.d("Is file exist",f.exists()+"");
                            Log.d("File Lenth",""+f.length());
                            Log.d("Return value",""+b);
                            loader.set(getContext());
                            loader.deleteSong(getContext(),give.get(position).getPosition());
                            give.remove(position); // give is Arraylist of Songs(datatype);
                            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            if(b)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Fail to Delete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    b.create().show();
                    d.dismiss();

                }
            });
            share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    d.dismiss();
                    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    share.setType("audio/*");
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, give.get(position).getSonguri());
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Audio"));
                }
            });
            properties.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    File f= new File(give.get(position).getSonguri().getPath());
                    long size = (f.length())/1024;
                    long mb= size/1024;
                    long kb= size%1024;

                    b.setMessage("Size:"+"\n"+"Size "+mb+"."+kb+" MB\n"+"Path:"+f.getAbsolutePath()+"\n");
                    b.setTitle(f.getName());
                    b.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
                    b.create().show();
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
    });
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    Log.d("fragment","instance saved");
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Fragment","Instance Restored");
}


public void intlistview()
{
    listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getContext(),give);
    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("Fragment","Destroyed");
    getActivity().unbindService(serviceConnection);
}

private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MusicService.LocalBinder binder = (MusicService.LocalBinder) service;
        musicService  =  binder.getService();
        mBound =true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mBound =false;
    }
};


public void allsongs()
{
    cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, where, null, orderBy);
    dataindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    albumindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
    titleindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
    durationindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
    artistindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
    {
        Songs song = new Songs();
        song.setalbum(cursor.getString(albumindex));
        song.settitle(cursor.getString(titleindex));
        song.setSonguri(Uri.parse(cursor.getString(dataindex)));
        song.setartist(cursor.getString(artistindex));
        song.setDuration(Long.decode(cursor.getString(durationindex)));
        song.setPosition(cursor.getPosition());
        this.give.add(song);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

}}
```

**Album Fragment**

```
public class AlbumFragment extends Fragment {
songDetailloader songDetailloader  = new songDetailloader();
public AlbumFragment() {
    super();
}
GridView gridView;
AlbumAdapter a;
private static ArrayList<Bitmap> image = new ArrayList<>();
LinearLayout linearLayout;
Cursor cursor ;
ImageView album;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Nullable
@Override


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.albumgridview,container,false);
    gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    album = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.albumart);
    /*Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.grid_layout_anim);
    GridLayoutAnimationController controller = new GridLayoutAnimationController(animation,0.2f,0.2f);
    gridView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);*/
    final TextView albumname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.albumname);
    cursor = songDetailloader.getAlbumCursor(getContext());
    if(image.size()==0)
    new getbitmaps().execute();

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String s = songDetailloader.albumart(position);
            Intent i = new Intent( getActivity() , AlbumDetail.class);
            Bundle b= new Bundle();
            b.putCharSequence("album",songDetailloader.album(position));
            i.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    return v;
  }

public class getbitmaps extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
     Bitmap b;

    public getbitmaps() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
        {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize= 2;
            b=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART)),options);
            if(b==null)
            {
                b=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART)));

            }
            image.add(b);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        a =new AlbumAdapter(getContext(),image);
        a.setCursor();
        gridView.setAdapter(a);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                songDetailloader.set(getContext());
            }
        }).start();

    }
}}
```

**Artist Fragment**

```
public class ArtistFragment extends Fragment {

ListView listView ;
ArrayList<Artists> aa = new ArrayList<>();
final String[] columns3 = {MediaStore.Audio.Artists._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST,MediaStore.Audio.Artists.NUMBER_OF_ALBUMS,MediaStore.Audio.Artists.NUMBER_OF_TRACKS};
final static String orderBy3 = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST;
public Cursor cursor3;

public ArtistFragment() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewofsongs,container,false);

    listView  = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    new artist().execute();
    return v;
}

public class artist extends AsyncTask<Void, Void ,Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        allartist();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        ArtistAdapter artistAdapter = new ArtistAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),aa);
        listView.setAdapter(artistAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i= new Intent(getActivity(), ArtistActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("artist", aa.get(position).getArtistname());
                i.putExtra("noofsongs",aa.get(position).getNofosongs());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void setInitialSavedState(SavedState state) {
    super.setInitialSavedState(state);
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void allartist()
{
    cursor3 = getContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns3, null, null, orderBy3);
    cursor3.moveToFirst();
    for(int i=0;i< cursor3.getCount() ;i++)
    {
        Artists art = new Artists();
        art.setArtistname(cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST)));
        art.setNoalbums(Integer.parseInt(cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.NUMBER_OF_ALBUMS))));
        art.setNofosongs(Integer.parseInt(cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.NUMBER_OF_TRACKS))));
        this.aa.add(art);
        cursor3.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor3.close();
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to add this property to you viewpager, in the `onCreate` method of your `MainActivity` :

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(fragments.size());
```

**Update**

Another thing you could try is:

In your `myfragment` override `getItemPosition` in this way:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {    
    return POSITION_NONE;    
}
```

And add this code in your `onCreate` of your `MainActivity`:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    int previousState;
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        if (previousState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING && state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

            pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        previousState = state;
    }
});
```

The aim of this code is not to be efficient, but to try to understand your problem.
Hope this can help you

Comment: i tried it with `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)` but problem remain same.

Comment: Is there is any way to do it more efficiently ?

Comment: Is TrackFragment the only fragment that becomes blank in your view pager scrolling?

Comment: Also: why are you using "setRetainInstance(true)" inside your fragments (into the onCreate method)? Try to remove them (from all 3 fragments inside the view pager) and test (in this case, return to "your version" of code to see what happens, only delete "setRetainInstance(true)" lines). In oder words, remove my suggested modifications that you did)

Comment: No TrackFragment is not only one which become blank

Comment: I am using "setRetainInstance(true)" just to retain contents on activity re-creation.

Comment: Ok, could you try to remove "setRetainInstance(true)" from fragments?

Comment: As you say, i tried it with removing "setRetainInstance(true)" but it make no changes.

Comment: Fragments are still becoming blank when i return to them again.

Comment: So, did you already tried to changing the parent class of myfragment from android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter to android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter ?

Comment: Ok, I think you have to play a little with them. So. try to remove for the moment the page transormer (comment line "viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());") and see what happens. After, if this don't help, try to make simpler the fragments, in order to make the viewpager work without problems. When you will reach a stable situation, you will add the missing parts..hope I was clear

Comment: Last thing, try to play around with last versions of libraries..the last design support libraries I suppose is 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'

Comment: Thanks , finally its gets solved by removing  "viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer()); ". But i don't know why this happens with page transformer can you please explain me the reason and what if i want to use page transformer.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to reply: as you can see here  [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setPageTransformer(boolean, android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.PageTransformer) )  , the first argument of setPageTransformer method has to be set to true if the PageTransformer requires page views to be drawn from last to first instead of first to last. So I think that the PageTransformer was reversing the order of fragment attached to viewPager. If you are curious, you can try to set this argument to 'false' and see what happens

Comment: Sorry, the link above is: [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setPageTransformer(boolean,android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.PageTransformer))